# Spring Boot: Could not resolve matching constructor when using scope: prototype

Tags: spring

## Problem

I'm having an issue where, any bean I define with the scope = `prototype` causes a `BeanCreationException`:

```swift
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myClass' defined in class path resource [application-context.xml]: Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:279)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1354)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:353)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:218)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1166)
    at com.example.coaching.BeanScopeDemoAppKt.main(BeanScopeDemoApp.kt:10)
    at com.example.coaching.BeanScopeDemoAppKt.main(BeanScopeDemoApp.kt)
```

## Example

This is the most basic example I could create that reproduced the problem...

#### MyClass.java:

Variation 1

```java
public class MyClass {
    public String doNothing() {
        return "Do nothing";
    }
}
```

Variation 2

```java
public class MyClass {

    public MyClass() {}

    public String doNothing() {
        return "Do nothing";
    }
}
```

#### application-context.xml

```xml
    <bean id="myClass"
          class="com.example.coaching.models.MyClass"
          scope="prototype">
    </bean>
```

#### MyApp.kt

```kotlin
class MyApp

fun main() {
    val context = ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beanScope-applicationContext.xml")
    val myClass = context.getBean("myClass", MyClass::class) as MyClass

    println(myClass.doNothing())
}
```

### Other Info

- I experienced this in a more complex project, but made this one to try to narrow down the problem and expected I would find something, but I have no clue.
- If I change the scope to `singleton`, it works fine.
- Happens with xml configuration as well as annotations
- Tried creating `MyClass` in both Kotlin and Java

#### Here's my pom.xml just in case

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Spring Demo Annotations</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <kotlin.version>1.4.31</kotlin.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
                    </args>
                    <compilerPlugins>
                        <plugin>spring</plugin>
                    </compilerPlugins>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Found any solution for this? I've just encountered this as well. If I @autowired it, it works with both "singleton" and "prototype", but when using context.getBean() I get the same exception. Looks like this bug: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/24955

Comment: No, unfortunately not.  I did see an [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/11744) that closely resembled this, but was supposed to have been fixed in v3.0.3.  Maybe it got re-introduced?